# ExtJS 3 locked: true not working

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am trying to lock the first column when scrolling. The `locked: true` and `enableautoLocking: true` did not work.

**Code snippet:**

```
var fieldColumn = {
    header: 'Field Name',
    css: 'background-color:#eee;cursor:auto;',
    sortable: false,
    dataIndex: 'fieldName',
    locked: true,
    autoSizeColumn: true,
    width: 140
};

this.columns.push(fieldColumn);

Ext.apply(this, {
    cls: 'fieldgrid',
    layout: 'table',
    store: this.fieldStore,
    autoScroll: true,
    loadMask: CNQR.admin.loadMask,
    plugins: headerCategoryGroup,
    colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        defaults: {
            sortable: false
        },
        columns: this.columns
    }),
    selModel: selectModel,
    tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
        ctCls: 'grayButtonToolBar  border-toolbar',
        buttons: [
            this.saveButton, this.cancelButton
        ]
    }),
    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        store: this.fieldStore,
        pageSize: this.pageSize,
        displayInfo: true,
        beforePageText: CNQR.getMsg('bbarBeforePageText'),
        afterPageText: CNQR.getMsg('bbarAfterPageText'),
        displayMsg: CNQR.getMsg('bbarDisplayMsg'),
        emptyMsg: CNQR.getMsg('bbarNoRecordsFound')
    })
});
CNQR.admin.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: Pretty sure locking doesn't exist in the Ext 3 framework. Maybe as an extension.

Comment: oh okay. Thanks reply. @Evan Trimboli do we have any alternate solution  if the locking is not available in ext 3 to make the column fixed.

Comment: The below link tells its available, am I missing something here. I am newbie to extJS, so pls help to understand if I am looking at correct thing.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.dd.DragDropMgr-property-locked

Comment: Did you even read the docs linked?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uzairpm/7F6nS/  this will help you

Answer (score 0):

More detailed answer is here try this

```
    var fieldColumn = {
    header: 'Field Name',
    css: 'background-color:#eee;cursor:auto;',
    sortable: false,
    dataIndex: 'fieldName',
    locked: true,
    autoSizeColumn: true,
    width: 140
};

this.columns.push(fieldColumn);

Ext.apply(this, {
    cls: 'fieldgrid',
    layout: 'table',
    store: this.fieldStore,
    autoScroll: true,
    loadMask: CNQR.admin.loadMask,
    plugins: headerCategoryGroup,
    view: new Ext.ux.grid.LockingGridView(),
    colModel: new Ext.ux.grid.LockingColumnModel({
        defaults: {
            sortable: false
        },
        columns: this.columns
    }),
    selModel: selectModel,
    tbar: new Ext.Toolbar({
        ctCls: 'grayButtonToolBar  border-toolbar',
        buttons: [
            this.saveButton, this.cancelButton
        ]
    }),
    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        store: this.fieldStore,
        pageSize: this.pageSize,
        displayInfo: true,
        beforePageText: CNQR.getMsg('bbarBeforePageText'),
        afterPageText: CNQR.getMsg('bbarAfterPageText'),
        displayMsg: CNQR.getMsg('bbarDisplayMsg'),
        emptyMsg: CNQR.getMsg('bbarNoRecordsFound')
    })
});
CNQR.admin.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: sure thank you so much Praveen and Evan. I will try and update you praveen. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: these two lines are not working.     view:new Ext.ux.grid.LockingGridView(),
    colModel: new Ext.ux.grid.LockingColumnModel

Comment: those are kind of plugins available in extjs source code path.. make sure they are available before proceeding .. see the fiddle for source of files    jsfiddle.net/uzairpm/7F6nS